# Code to copy filter sheet1 to sheet2 using lastrow lastcolumn gets error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply lastrow lastcolumn, but not getting it right.

I get the error "The extracted range has a missing or illegal field name"

Thanks

```
Sub FilterCopyToOtherSheet2()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim colChr As String


    With Sheets("Comments-Tableau")
        lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

Sheets("Comments-Tableau").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AdvancedFilter   Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Comments").Range("A1"), _
Unique:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Comments-Tableau").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error

Comment: All of this is highlighted `Sheets("Comments-Tableau").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AdvancedFilter   Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Comments").Range("A1"), _
Unique:=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but this just might do it:

```
Sheets("Comments-Tableau").UsedRange.offset(1,1).Copy
Sheets("Comments").Activate
Sheets("Comments").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False ' exit copy mode
```

Check out [Missing or Illegal Field Name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173112) You need to include headers in the copy operation.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AdvancedFilter    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), _
Unique:=False
```

Comment: Hello D_Bester thanks your code works well. the `advanced filter` works well I was hoping to learn how to apply the lastcolumn lastrow method